# Using Dapper (or other NuGet packages) with Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, nuget, dapper

I am currently working on a Xamarin.Android project for a FieldService app. I looked into the standard Xamarin SQLite.NET component for the Data Access Layer, but it does not meet my needs. (I cannot create a PK with multiple fields, for example).

I tried to use the Dapper framework, since I have more experience with that and I think it's pretty awesome.

Couldn't get it to work with Xamarin.Android. I am using Xamarin with Visual Studio 2013. Anyone who knows how to do this?

I tried 3 ways:

1. Adding Dapper to a Xamarin.Android Class Library. - No errors, but Dapper was not under the `References` group in solution explorer and I couldn't use the namespace `Dapper`
2. Adding Dapper to a "normal" .net Class Library. - Everything worked, I was able to add it, I could use the `Dapper` namespace and `Query` methods etc. BUT there was an error referencing the project to the main Xamarin.Android application project. (different target framework)
3. Adding Dapper to a Portable Class Library targeting .NET Framework 4.5 and Xamarin.Android. - Error when adding the NuGet package.

Brief question: How to add Dapper (or other NuGet packages) to Xamarin.Android?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should provide the details when you post the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dapper NuGet package contains assemblies that target:

1. .NET 3.5
2. .NET 4.0
3. .NET 4.5

So you will not be able to the NuGet package with an Xamarin Android project since this project will target MonoAndroid.

Dapper would need to be recompiled against the MonoAndroid target framework, if possible. Otherwise you would need to look at other alternatives.

Looking at the Dapper GitHub site all the various classes available in the NuGet package are from one [SqlMapper.cs file](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/blob/master/Dapper%20NET40/SqlMapper.cs) which seems to compile inside an Android project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! appreciate it. By the thing about SqlMapper.cs, do you mean I can download the .cs file and include it in my project manually? I guess the only downside will be that I won't get automatic update notifications. Maybe that is a good way of doing it. I'll look into it and accept your answer if I think it meets my needs. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes download the file and add it to your project. Ideally the owners of the Dapper NuGet package would build it against MonoAndroid and include the assembly in the NuGet package.

Comment: Installing the NuGet package and manually referencing the downloaded .dll worked too, but I ended up using your approach and included the `SqlMapper.cs` file to my project. Thanks!

Comment: @avb, which downloaded DLL are you referring to?  My guess would be the PCL version, but I'd like to know which you were referring to.

Comment: @MarqueIV It has been a while, but from what I remember I could download the NuGet via the package manager, Visual Studio then gave an error "This package does not support this project type" or something like that. But if I then manually added a reference to the downloaded .dll (in packages folder), it worked.

Comment: Thanks! Definitely encouraging news!

Comment: @MarqueIV I think some other issue came up doing that, because like I said, I ended up including the `SqlMapper.cs` in the project, since it's just that file you need. That has been working fine for me the past 1,5 years ;)

Comment: DNX?  Refresh my mem.